# Why does bind cols generate two new columns?

Tags: r

I have previously written a function that worked fine. Now, one year later it does no longer work. I found that bind_cols does not give the same output as before.

I have to datasets that I want to join, the common column is m_curve. When I now run bind_cols, there are two different columns:

New names:

- m_curve -> m_curve...4
- m_curve -> m_curve...5

Why? And how do I get this to work (one common column with m_curve)

```
df1 <- structure(list(Temp = c(3.5, 3.3, 3.2), RH = c(87.2, 87.1, 87.2
), Date = structure(c(1416340800, 1416344400, 1416348000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), m_curve = c("day", "day", "day")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(m_curve = c("day", "day", "day"), tF = c(0, 0, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

bind_cols(df1,df2)
```

Comment: Because there is a duplicate column 'm_curve' and in data.frame, tibble, it is not allowed to have duplicate column names.  May be you need a join or merge, but make sure that there are no dupes for the `by` column

Comment: If the data is in consistent column order, you could modify to `bind_cols(df1,df2[-1])` to eliminate the repetition.

Comment: Thank you! The strange thing is that this has worked previously on the same datasets that I am using now...

Answer (score 0):

You probably had some kind of ID column in your former project? You could use the `rownames` of both data sets to `merge` them.

```
df1$id <- rownames(df1)
df2$id <- rownames(df2)

df3 <- merge(df1, df2)
df3
#   m_curve id Temp   RH                Date tF
# 1     day  1  3.5 87.2 2014-11-18 20:00:00  0
# 2     day  2  3.3 87.1 2014-11-18 21:00:00  0
# 3     day  3  3.2 87.2 2014-11-18 22:00:00  0
```

Should also work with `bind_cols()`, don't know from which package it stems from, though, because you didn't provide the `library`.